# Allow "invalid" html markup in partial view in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with generating html with razor engine. In my case I have a app where a stored procedure lists a nested tree and have calculated how many submenus, how many siblings etc there are. And I need to have some logic in my partial view. And razor engine doesn't seem to like it since it seems to be invalid markup. How can I fix this to it prints out what I want?

```
<ul class="menu">
    @foreach (var item in Model.NestedMenus)
    {
        if (item.StartNode > 0)
        {
            if (item.SubMenus > 0)
            {
            <li style="submenu">
            }
            else
            {             
            <li style="menu">        
            }
        @item.MenuName      
        }
        else
        {
        </li>
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Must I use some old school Response.Write or summet? :)

/L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [prefix the lines with `@:`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) to prevent Razor from trying to parse the markup.
Otherwise, it will need to parse the markup in order to end the code block outside the top layer of markup.